# Allocating 2D array without using array notation

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, 2d

Been working on an assignment that requires creating and traversing 2D array of integers, but without using array notation, such as a[1][2] or even *(*(a+i)+j). It is required to use pointer arithmetic to access each individual element.

So far my approach has been to allocate it as such. Included are comments that show what I *think* my code should be accomplishing, feel free to correct me otherwise.

```
int **a;  // 2d array, or pointer to array of pointers
row = 5;     
count = 5;

// allocate space
a = new int* [row];   // create array of pointers
int *p = *m;          // point to first array
for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
{
    a = new int [col];  // create space within each array
    a++;
}
```

Row and columns are dynamic, and is passed in as parameters in the function. 5 is just used as an example here.

To fill the 5 x 5 2d array with elements (example 5), I use the following :

```
int *pRow = *a;            // get array of pointers
int *pElement = &pRow[0];  // get first element from the first array
int r = 0;
int c = 0;

while (r < row)
{
    while (c < col)
    {
        int element = 5;    
        *pElement = element;  // set first element to 5
        pElement++;           // go to next element
        c++;                  
    }
    c = 0;
    r++;
}
```

The problem is that *pElement = element throws a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error so there's something that I'm doing wrong.

Could anyone point out my mistake or correct my understanding of pointers, if it is found wanting?

--

Also, as a side note, is it correct to say,

```
int *pRow = *a; 
int *pElement = &pRow[0];
```

accesses the same thing (which is the first element) as

```
int *pElement = &**a[0];
```

Comment: I read "assignment" to mean "homework" so retagged. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: related [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/) on arrays.

Comment: @badgerr yes you are correct, no amendment necessary!

Comment: @FredOverflow great FAQ you've written! very informative.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just declare a simple array. A 2D array can be flatten into a 1d. It would greatly simplify the arithmetic.

```
int* a = new int[row * column];

for (int iRow = 0; iRow < (row - 1); ++iRow)
    for (int jCol = 0; jCol < (column - 1) ; ++jCol)
{
// here you can access a[iRow * row + jCol]
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes a 1d would be preferable, but it is part of the requirements that I declare it as a 2d array, or rather int **a

Answer (score 0):

```
*pElement = element throws a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error
```

You will have to reset `pElement` between each column, right now, it will continue up to 20 steps after the limit of the first column.

Then you have to be more careful using the `&` operator. It takes the address of the variable. The [0] operation takes the first value in an array, these two means that: `&pRow[0] == pRow => true`

And since you are not supposed to use array notation, `pRow` would suffice for that.

This is also true semantically, however, as I stated above, there is no need for `&var[0]`, it would evaluate to `var` anyway.

Also, as a side note, is it correct to say,

```
int *pRow = *a; 
int *pElement = &pRow[0];
```

accesses the same thing (which is the first element) as

```
int *pElement = &**a[0];
```